# Approximation by regular curves

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\gamma:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ be a smooth curve. We say $\gamma$ is regular iff $\gamma^\prime $ does not have any zeros. Can we approximate any smooth curve $\gamma$ uniformly by regular curves $(\gamma_n)_n$ such that $\gamma_n^\prime\to \gamma^\prime$ uniformly too.